# Subclass column generated from propensity score matching results

Tags: r, match, propensity-score-matching

I did a propensity score matching but the result was composed of different columns.

```
matching <- matchit(score ~ drug_period+first_dose+sex+age, ratio=10, method='nearest', data=data)
matched=match.data(matching)
```

I wanted to do 1:10 propensity score matching using 'MatchIt' and when I checked 'matched' table as a result, **3 new columns were generated; distance, weights, subclass.**
However, **when I ran same code at different computer with different dataset, there was no 'subclass' column at the result table; only distance and weights columns were generated** (matched table).

I ran same codes at different computer, but why are the two results columns different?

If anyone who know about this, please explain about this.

Comment: Could you provide your two datasets using `dput(your dataset)`?

Comment: Check the version of `MatchIt` installed. Prior to version 4.0.0, nearest neighbor matching did not return pair membership (the `subclass` column). As of version 4.0.0, it does.